# custom action in user timeline not working

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post custom action in facebook timeline and also in page timeline.

Here is the sample code.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
attachment = { 
                        'name': 'headline', 
                        'link': link, 
                        'actions' : { 'name' : 'Call here',  'link': str(apply_link) },
                        'description': job_description,
                        'picture': image_url
                    }
graph.put_wall_post(message, attachment= attachment)
```

Post to page wall is successful and post to user wall is unsuccessful(no error message, but custom action is missing).

Is this because of some specific reason?

Is there any specific way to do this ?

### Observation

I don't know why, but the custom action appeared in the next day.